# Error creating bean with name 'cargoDaoImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Estou tentando subir meu projeto spring porém obtenho o seguinte erro.

```
   15:17:43.079 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
    15:17:43.081 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
    15:17:43.081 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/home/lemospadilha/Documentos/SpringTreinaweb/demo-mvc/target/classes/]

      .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

    2018-09-01 15:17:43.332  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.curso.boot.DemoMvcApplication        : Starting DemoMvcApplication on lemospadilha-300E5M-300E5L with PID 25314 (/home/lemospadilha/Documentos/SpringTreinaweb/demo-mvc/target/classes started by lemospadilha in /home/lemospadilha/Documentos/SpringTreinaweb/demo-mvc)
    2018-09-01 15:17:43.334  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] c.l.curso.boot.DemoMvcApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2018-09-01 15:17:43.513  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@262e759b: startup date [Sat Sep 01 15:17:43 BRT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.382  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8090 (http)
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.416  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.417  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.420  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.483  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.483  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 973 ms
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.526  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.528  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.529  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.529  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.529  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.529  INFO 25314 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'resourceUrlEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.552  WARN 25314 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cargoDaoImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.lemospadilha.curso.boot.dao.AbstractDAO] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4843eafe]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.555  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.568  INFO 25314 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

    Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
    2018-09-01 15:17:44.575 ERROR 25314 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cargoDaoImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.lemospadilha.curso.boot.dao.AbstractDAO] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4843eafe]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:261) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1120) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:398) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:330) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1258) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at com.lemospadilha.curso.boot.DemoMvcApplication.main(DemoMvcApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.lemospadilha.curso.boot.dao.AbstractDAO] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@4843eafe]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:659) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:556) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:569) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:541) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:244) ~[spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityManager
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:641) ~[spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar:5.0.8.RELEASE]
        ... 27 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManager
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:148) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar:2.0.4.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
        ... 31 common frames omitted
```

Segue minha classe CargoDAO e sua interface.

```
package com.curso.boot.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.curso.boot.domain.Cargo;

@Repository
public class CargoDaoImpl extends AbstractDAO<Cargo, Long> implements CargoDAO {

}
```

Interface:

```
package com.curso.boot.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.curso.boot.domain.Cargo;

public interface CargoDAO {

    void save(Cargo cargo);

    void update(Cargo cargo);

    void delete(Long id);

    Cargo findById(Long id);

    List<Cargo> findAll();
}
```

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.EntityManager`: tem certeza que está no classpath a `javax.persistence-api`?

Comment: Experimenta tirar a sua interface, no trecho 'implements CargoDAO'

Answer (score 0):

Já tive um problema parecido, verifica se na sua AbstractDao se está de dessa forma:

```
private final Class<T> entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)  getClass().getAnnotatedSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0`];
```

Se estiver tente utilizando o .getGenericSuperclass

```
private final Class<T> entityClass = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType)  getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Acho que assim irá funcionar.